# Is there a write function that corresponds to fread() in the data.table package?

Tags: r, data.table

The `fread()` function in the data.table package for R offers impressive speed and ease of use when reading large CSV files or such. Unfortunately  I haven't managed to find a similar function to *write* CSV files from R. I have of course tried `write.csv()`, but I find it appallingly slow when writing really big data files.

So: does anyone know if there's anything similar to fread() for writing files?

Comment: If you have massive data a CSV might not be the best possibility to store it. Have you considered using a database?

Comment: is writing in a .csv your actual goal? or just having your data stored on the disk? In which case you can update your question and we can start talking about `ff` package and similar solutions.

Comment: `fwrite` for CSV was introduced in [data.table 1.9.8](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.4/topics/fwrite) 11/2016, [issue #580](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/580) . Voting to reopen this.

Comment: This question should stay closed as it is a tool-request. The fact that the `fwrite` was introduced later doesn't change anything about that.

Comment: No, for two years now, this question is **not** a tool request and should have been reopened, since `fwrite` was added to `data.table` itself.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` was introduced in data.table version 1.9.8, and is a very fast option for writing files. [See the help page here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fwrite.html).